# Suggestion for java based GIS sdk for desktop application

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java, javafx

I am developing a desktop GIS application using JavaFX that needs to run on Linux. I have been using ArcGIS java sdk and it is really good for all my requirements. But when I started testing it on our actual field machines it is not working. My client is using an AMD driver on their Centos machines and they not ready to change it because they say they found this as a solution to many of their problems. Some how the ArcGIS java sdk not working very well with the AMD driver so I am searching for an alternative. I really liked ArcGIS it has all the features that I required. So far I was not able to find a good alternative for that, can somebody pleas suggest an alternative solution.

For reference on of my coworker posted the problem in another thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114488/problem-with-arcgisruntimesdk-for-java-on-centos-6-2-after-installing-amd-cataly

I tried with the latest 10.2.4 version still not working.

Comment: I didn't use any of the java based GIS applications, however I have heard good things about two of them. The first one is Jgrass (https://code.google.com/p/jgrass/), the second is Whitebox (http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/). About the second one, you can ask @WhiteboxDev, he could provide additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that there are several open-source GIS and spatial analysis platforms that target the Java virtual machine (JVM). [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/), for example, provides a fairly comprehensive Java-based spatial library. If you're only interested in vector data analysis, then I can certainly recommend the [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) as a basis for spatial analysis development. I am involved in the development of another Java-based GIS called [Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/). It's developed under the GNU General Public Licence and so the source code (available [here](https://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/)) is there for you to use (under the conditions of the licence) and to inspect, modify, and improve upon. Another interesting Java based open-source GIS that I only recently discovered is [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/).

As an alternative to starting your own new project, you may consider joining one of these existing projects. I know that for the Whitebox project, I'm always keen on getting volunteers involved in development and I'm sure that the other projects are similarly interested in growing their development team. In that way, instead of developing your own new GIS (which I can attest is a massive undertaking) you can help to make an existing project even better. Any way you go, I wish you the best of luck and you should know that the JVM is a fantastic cross-platform development environment for GIS work.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions I already started looking at GeoTools.

Comment: Accepting this as answer because I was able to implement most of features using GeoTools